# Can I see who voted for what after I die?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, up-votes, votes

I would like to know who has up- and (most importantly!) downvoted my questions. Will I find out after I die? What do different religions/beliefs say about this? I would happily convert to see the votes in the afterlife!

Slightly related: Can I leave a will (similarly to organ donation) that after I die other people can see what I've voted for? I wonder what will happen to my user...

In fact, is there a way to make my votes public right now?

Comment: "In fact, is there a way to make my votes public right now?"
[Just see.](http://mathoverflow.net/users/current?tab=votes)

Comment: Makes me wonder: can I bequeath reputation points in my will?

Comment: "I would like to know how has up- and (most importantly!) downvoted my questions. Will I find out after I die?" You can find out right away [here](http://mathoverflow.net/help/privileges/vote-down). Oh, you meant "who", maybe that's for next year then. :-)

Comment: @quid: oops, thx, fixed. How did you make that "just see" thing?

Comment: Using `current` instead of a userID (and displayname) in the link will take each (registered) user to their version of the site. You should be able to see it by hovering over the link rather than following it.

Comment: :-) This reminds me of the joke: "Two unborn twins talk just before birth: -- Is there life after birth? -- Very unlikely. Nobody ever came back".

Comment: Joro +1: Didn't know this joke, but definitely one of my favorites now :-)

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN What about a chat channel about (math) jokes? If you are interested please make a channel on chat and ping me with the URL.

Answer (score 8):

As I understand it, one destination has an Ethereal API to the Stack Exchange databases.  Unfortunately one only has assembly language to write the routines to use it, and no linker: you have to compute your own entry points.  Also, none of the keyboards work properly and you have to keep adjusting the display out of character mode.

Another destination has more capabilities like the Ethereal APi, but the emphasis is on all possibilities, and the indexing system does not catalog which possibility you came from.

A third destination has the capabilities, but no reliable net connection.

I recommend changing your belief system.

Gerhard "Ask Me About Belief Systems" Paseman, 2016.04.01.

Comment: I assume you are writing from experience, right?

Comment: I always write from experience.  What I write about isn't always from first hand observation.  As the poster is interested in answers which may depend on belief systems, this gives some latitude in the responses.  Gerhard "Feel Free To Be Entertained/ing" Paseman, 2016.04.03.

Answer (score 6):

I think the religion of [copyism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missionary_Church_of_Kopimism), which holds that information is sacred and must be preserved, is the one you should look into.  The information as to who voted for what is certainly something you get in copyist heaven.